# SQL Select, is it possible to merge specific dupe rows into 1 based on a key?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm a little stumped on this. I have a table that looks like the following:

```
Group_Key      Trigger_Type        Event_Type         Result_Id
1                   A                   A                 1
2                   B                   B                 2
3                   C                   C                 3 
3                   C                   C                 4
4                   E                   E                 5
5                   F                   F                 6
5                   F                   F                 7
```

There are rows that will have the same survey (all columns should be the same aside from result_id) key but they will have a different result_Id. Is it possible to do a select on the table that grabs the rows and instead of returning 2 rows because of the result_id, it groups those ones that have dupes into a single row with the result_id being a concatenated string? So for instance, return this:

```
Group_Key      Trigger_Type        Event_Type         Result_Id
1                   A                   A                 1
2                   B                   B                 2
3                   C                   C                 3,4 
4                   E                   E                 5
5                   F                   F                 6,7
```

Is this possible?

Thank you,

Comment: Hint:  `STRING_AGG()`.

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using? Where are the results of this query going to be used? (it's often better to do this in your reporting tool rather than in the database).

Comment: why over tax the reporting tool when he/she has a sql server to filter out the dups.

Comment: Thanks for the replies everyone. I am using SQL server 2012. Unfortunately it looks STRING_AGG() is not a built in function with 2012. Is there any other way of doing this?

Comment: You can use a recursive CTE in SQL Server 2012 to replicate the functionality of `string_agg()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example using a recursive CTE to replicate the functionality of `string_agg()`.    This example is from the [upsert scripts for execsql](https://bitbucket.org/rdnielsen/execsql_upsert/src/default/), and was written by Elizabeth Shea.  It will have to be modified for your particular use, substituting your own column names for the execsql variable references.

```
if object_id('tempdb..#agg_string') is not null drop table #agg_string;
with enum as 
    (
    select
        cast(!!#string_col!! as varchar(max)) as agg_string,
        row_number() over (order by !!#order_col!!) as row_num
    from
        !!#table_name!!
    ),
agg as 
    (
    select
        one.agg_string,
        one.row_num
    from
        enum as one
    where
        one.row_num=1
    UNION ALL
    select
        agg.agg_string + '!!#delimiter!!' + enum.agg_string as agg_string,
        enum.row_num
    from 
        agg, enum
    where
        enum.row_num=agg.row_num+1
    )
select
agg_string 
into #agg_string
from agg
where row_num=(select max(row_num) from agg);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Gordon Linoff's hint you can `GROUP BY` the values that should be the same and concatenate the other values in one row using `STRING_AGG`:

```
SELECT Group_Key, Trigger_Type, Event_Type, STRING_AGG(Result_Id, ',') as ResultId
FROM myTable
GROUP BY Group_Key, Trigger_Type, Event_Type
```

Answer (score 0):

I would add the ordering of values to MicSim's solutions as follows:

```
select Group_Key, Trigger_Type, Event_Type,
string_agg(Result_Id, ',') within group (order by Result_Id)
from survey
group by Group_Key, Trigger_Type, Event_Type
```

Answer (score 0):

MS-SQL Server will not recognise STRING_AGG function. Try stuff() as shown below:

```
SELECT Group_Key ,Trigger_Type, Event_Type,   
STUFF(
    (SELECT CONCAT( Result_Id , ', ') AS [text()]
    FROM [dbo].[TestTable] t2  
    WHERE t1.Group_Key = t2.Group_Key
    AND t1.Trigger_Type = t2.Trigger_Type
    AND t1.Event_Type= t2.Event_Type
    ORDER BY Group_Key ,Trigger_Type, Event_Type
    FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 0, '') AS Result_Id 
FROM [dbo].[TestTable] t1 

GROUP BY Group_Key ,Trigger_Type, Event_Type
```

Hope this helps.